# Android : Can I use My Entity class using DISTINCT query Room Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am using **Room Database** for storing chat, I have one group table and I want to fetch three parameters like this query

My Group Entity class is **GroupUserEntity.kt**

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT group_id, group_name, group_image FROM group_user_table")
fun getAllGroups() : List<ENTITY_CLASS>
```

I am not able to use my Group Entity class(GroupUserEntity.kt) over **ENTITY_CLASS**, forcefully I have to make new **Entity class**(Pojo Class) to fetch those three values.

So my questions is, there is any way to utilize my **old Entity class**(GroupUserEntity.kt) to fetch all groups? or I need to make a **new POJO** class for that?

Comment: Have you made the fields that you are not fetching, `nullable`, in your `GroupUserEntity.kt` file ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on number of variables in your GroupUserEntity.kt.

If for example you have group_id, group_name, group_image and group_category (**total 4**) in GroupUserEntity.kt and you are fetching data for only **3** variables then it will show you an error. (**Cursor mismatch**).

To avoid this either call ALL the columns values from database to match GroupUserEntity.kt, or create a new POJO.